# How can I make the npc character to rotate slowly facing the player while changing animator transitions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have in the soldier animator a Grounded transition and this is start with this transition by default. Then I did that after 3 second it will slowly change between the two transitions from Grounded to Rifle_Aiming_Idle.

But To see how it's working and if it's working good like I wanted I had to turn off the FPSController Camera( FPSCamera is turned off gray ). So when running the game the active camera is the Main Camera and the CM vcam1 ( Cinemachine virtual camera ).

But I want to make more with this cutscene.
I want that first the cutscene will start only when the player the FPSController will exit a door:

This script is attached to the FPSController:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;

public class SpaceshipCutscene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform npc;
    public float cutsceneDistance = 5f;
    public float speed;

    private bool moveNpc = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (moveNpc)
        {
            float travel = Mathf.Abs(speed) * Time.deltaTime;

            Vector3 direction = (player.position - npc.position).normalized;
            Quaternion lookrotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
            npc.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npc.rotation, lookrotation, Time.deltaTime * 5);
            Vector3 position = npc.position;
            position = Vector3.MoveTowards(position, player.position, travel);
            npc.position = position;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Horizontal_Doors_Kit")
            moveNpc = true;
    }
}
```

I want that when the player the FPSController exit the door start the cutscene and while it's playing/doing the cutscene I want at the same time also making the soldier with the animator to rotate slowly facing the FPSController.

FPSController exit the door > Soldier changing slowly from grounded to aiming mode and Soldier rotating slowly facing the FPSController.

My problems are how to start the cinemachine cutscene when the FPSController exit the door and how to make the Soldier( npc ) to rotate slowly facing the FPSController.

What I tried in the Update in the script is not working good.
It's making the npc moving and not rotating slowly good enough fro the cutscene like I wanted.

[image: Anim]

And maybe for the rotation part I should use the Cinemachine and not doing it in the script ? Maybe I should using Timeline here too for the rotation part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution for what I needed:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;

public class SpaceshipCutscene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform npc;
    public Camera FPSCamera;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    public Animator anim;
    public float rotationSpeed = 3f;

    private bool moveNpc = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (moveNpc)
        {
          Vector3 dir = player.position - npc.position;
        dir.y = 0; // keep the direction strictly horizontal
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
        // slerp to the desired rotation over time
        npc.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npc.rotation, rot, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Horizontal_Doors_Kit")
        {
            FPSCamera.enabled = false;
            mainCamera.enabled = true;
            moveNpc = true;
            anim.SetTrigger("SoldierAimingTrigger");
        }
    }
}
```